# PasswordChangeView not redirecting to PasswordChangeDoneView (or changing the password)

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am trying to use the Django authentication views. My login/logout views are working without a problem.

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from account import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dashboard, name = 'dashboard'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name = 'login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name = 'logout'),
    path('password_change', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name = 'password_change'),
    path('password_change/done', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name = 'password_change_done'),

]
```

password_change_form.html:

```
{% block body %}
  <h1>Change your password</h1>

    <p>Please use the following form to change your password:</p>
    <div class = 'password-change-form'>
      <form class="" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Change">
      </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

password_change_done.html:

```
{% block body %}
  <h1>Password Changed Successfully</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

I can navigate to `/password_change` and see the form, but when I fill it in and submit it in I am redirected to `/login` (I have made sure I was already logged in) and the password does not change. Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Well the action should not be `'login'`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Tried to copy and paste the form for speed:(  Sorry and thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you specified `{% url 'login' %}` for the `action="…"` parameter, you need to change it with:

```
{% block body %}
  <h1>Change your password</h1>

    <p>Please use the following form to change your password:</p>
    <div class = 'password-change-form'>
      <form class="" action="{% url 'password_change' %}" method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Change">
      </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{% url 'password_change' %}`, then this view redirects to `'password_change_done'` ?